# Papertrail store associated model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I want to store associated tables data in the same papertrial::Version type so that fetching changes for a table and its associated table is easier.

```
class User
  has_paper_trail
  has_one :profile
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`User.first.versions` will return changes in the columns of the users table. How to get changes in the profile table and comments table when we query for `User.first.versions`. Is it possible to store in user versions while making a commit to profile table.

Comment: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail Papertrail has great docs is this not covered there?

Comment: Two possibilities: See docs section [4.c. Storing Metadata](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata) or perhaps [4.b. Associations](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4b-associations). Very different solutions, evaluate them carefully. Good luck.